# Complete Async throws message lock exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azureservicebus

I have a worker service listening to service bus queues and I am trying to export large data to blob storage. The entire process is taking around 7mins to complete. I complete the message after the process is  completed, but the Complete async mehthod throws MessageLockException. Below is my code

```
public class MessageReceiverService<T> : MessageReceiver, IHostedService where T : class, new()
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IProcessData<T> _processData;

        public MessageReceiverService(string queueName, string connectionString, IProcessData<T> processData, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) : base(connectionString, queueName)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ServiceBusQueuesService<T>>();
            _processData = processData;
        }
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"BusListenerService starting; registering message handler.");
            _logger.LogInformation($"BusListenerService started listening to the connection {ServiceBusConnection.Endpoint.AbsoluteUri}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"BusListenerService started listening to the queue {Path}");

            var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
            {
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 1, //change to 1 when debugging in local to debug current call.
                AutoComplete = false,
                MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
            };

            RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessageAsync, messageHandlerOptions);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
        {
            _logger.LogError(exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception, "Message handler encountered an exception");
            var context = exceptionReceivedEventArgs.ExceptionReceivedContext;

            _logger.LogDebug($"- Endpoint: {context.Endpoint}");
            _logger.LogDebug($"- Entity Path: {context.EntityPath}");
            _logger.LogDebug($"- Executing Action: {context.Action}");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var messageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
            var messagePayload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(messageData);

            _logger.LogInformation($"{message.CorrelationId} | BusListenerService received item.");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Message expires in {message.ExpiresAtUtc.ToLocalTime()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Message properties expires in {message.SystemProperties.LockedUntilUtc.ToLocalTime()}");
                Console.WriteLine($"LockToken set in {message.SystemProperties.IsLockTokenSet}");
                Console.WriteLine($"LockToken in {message.SystemProperties.LockToken}");

                await _processData.Process(messagePayload);
                
                await CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken); //MessageLockException when calling this method after the process is done.
            }
            catch (MessageLockLostException mllex)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"MessageLock exception occured: {mllex.Message}");
                if (mllex.InnerException != null)
                    _logger.LogInformation($"MessageLock exception occured: {mllex.InnerException.Message}");

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                await DeadLetterAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken, ex.Message);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation($"{message.CorrelationId} | BusListenerService processed item.");
        }

        public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"BusListenerService stopping.");
            await CloseAsync();
        }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me to identify/understand the issue?

Comment: I'd check the timings. We have almost the same setup using service bus & can't see anything different in what your're doing

Comment: I always warn folks about `MaxAutoRenewDuration` - it's the best effort at most and is never guaranteed as it's a client-side originated operation and can fail.

Comment: What is the Lockduration for the queue ? Is it Default (30 Seconds)?

Comment: @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT it is default 1 min

Answer (score 0):

`MaxAutoRenewDuration` is client level operation.

This is how it works :
LockDuration period is about to expire, the client will issue a request to the broker renew the lock.

The default, Lockduration is 30 seconds (Last I checked at my end ).

[image]

Now in your case, for every end of 1 minute  ( within 30 minutes or until message is marked complete ) there is a request sent to service bus to have an lock extended.

So for 7 minutes process, there will be at least 7 times clients request to renew the lock. If even, one of the renew operation has failed because any reason, the lock is released for the message.

**Few reasons for the failure of the renewal process :**

- The client is too busy that it was unable to complete the request in a timely manner or
  very slow network
- There was some issue at the service bus end (high utilization, noisy neighbor, etc. )

Having said that, you can consider increase the lockduration to 5 minutes (Maximum). In that case there will be only one instance of the client level operation considering the 7 minute processing time(*I'd recommend to try reducing the processing time as well to fall within the maximum lockduration*). The probability of this failing would be comparatively less.

To change the lock duration :

[image]

You click on the change.